# Obtaining varied results using the grep command

Tags: linux, error-handling, grep, status, exitstatus

For example, I have a file:

```
$ cat test.file
a
b
c
```

If I `grep` with output, I got `echo $?` to `0`:

```
$ grep a test.file
a

$ echo $?
0
```

But if I `grep` without output, I got `echo $?` to `1`

```
$ grep x test.file

$ echo $?
1
```

Because I got `$?` to `1`, my pipeline with this command is failed.

What should I do to get consistent result as `0`, since `grep` has no output is fine to me.

Answer (score 3):

Add  `|| true` to the end of the statement, for example:

```
grep x test.file > out.file || true
```

I prefer the above approach, since it is more explicit and more concise than setting/resettings `errexit` or `pipefail` like so:

```
set -o errexit
# ...
set +o errexit
grep x test.file > out.file
set -o errexit
```

This is especially true if you have multiple `grep` commands scattered throughout the script.

Comment: it will always be `true`. For some other reasons, for example, if the file is not exist, I still get `true`

Comment: @Bill The same can be said about most other methods. If you want to differentiate between `grep` not finding a match and `grep` not finding the file, you need to check whether `$?` is 1 or 2. That can be done trivially, but simply adding `|| true` is not the way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Simply add an `or true` and the end

```
grep not_found myinput.file || : # same as /usr/bin/true
```

Answer (score 2):

A command in a pipeline failing only causes the rest of the pipeline to fail if you previously called `set -o pipefail` - if you don't want that behavior then don't set that option.

Having said that, you could just use awk instead:

```
$ awk '/a/' test.file
a
$ echo $?
0
```

```
$ awk '/x/' test.file
$ echo $?
0
```

Comment: good idea. That's consistant output

Answer (score 0):

You could use `sed` much like Ed's `awk` [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77560819/8656552).

```
$: sed -n '/a/p' tst; echo $?
a
0

$: sed -n '/x/p' tst; echo $?
0
```

But as a rule, user3922090's [||:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77560539/8656552) is my go-to for any time I don't want an error return, regardless of the result.

```
$: grep a file ||: ; echo $?
a
0

$: grep x file ||: ; echo $?
0
```

The `||` executes it's right-hand only if the left-hand returns a fail/error exit code, so if the `grep` finds a match, `grep`'s zero is printed... but if `grep` doesn't, it returns an error, and `||` executes the `:`, which is a synonym for `true`, which just unconditionally returns a zero code - which is what gets printed by `echo`.